# Do you say "I accidentally opened the suitcase uncontrollably and the clothes poped out / spilled out over the floor"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [pop](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pop) 1 /pɒp $ pɑːp/ ●●○ S3 verb (popped, popping)     1 COME OUT/OFF
>   [intransitive always + adverb/preposition] to come suddenly or
>   unexpectedly out of or away from something
>
> **pop out/off/up etc**
>
> The top button popped off my shirt.
>
> The ball popped out of Smith’s hands and onto the ground.
>
> **out/up popped something**
>
> The egg cracked open and out popped a tiny head.
>
> The lid popped open and juice spilled all over the floor.

---

> [spill](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spill_1?q=spill) ​[intransitive] + adv./prep. (of people) to come out of a place
>   in large numbers and spread out
>
> The doors opened and people spilled into the street.
>
> After the clubs closed, the drinkers spilled out into the streets.

[image]

Do you say "**I accidentally opened the suitcase uncontrollably and the clothes popped out / spilled out over the floor**"?

I am not sure if "**pop out**" or "**spill out**" are suitable words in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pop* suggests an active movement, jumping or being thrown out. *Spill* is better for clothes falling out of a suitcase - or you could use *fell* or *tumbled.*

I think most native speakers would say something like *The suitcase came open and...*

Comment: when we say "a bag came open/undone/loose etc", we meant it happened accidentally right? Maybe the buckle was loose for example, right?.

Comment: Well, you did say _accidentally_!

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pop) offers these definition for **pop out** and **spill**:

> pop out: to move **quickly** and suddenly, especially from a closed space
>
> spill: to (cause to) **flow**, move, fall, or spread over the edge or outside the limits of something

Note the highlighted words in these definitions. We generally use **pop out** when something happens quickly, and we use the word **spill** about things that flow... mainly liquids, but also fluid solids like sugar or sand.

If the suitcase were very full, and the moment it is opened, the clothes were thrown quickly across the floor,  you could say "pop". If the clothes simply fell slowly to the floor when the case opens, then **fall out** is the best term to use.